# Is it possible to make the main function wait from a thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

This is a workaround program where I need to a logic like this:

1. Trigger a job in a normal function
2. Check if a certain directory is created in another Thread
3. Whenever this directory is created, pause the main thread, do some work in this thread and continue execution of the main thread.

Is there a way I can pause the main thread from another thread in Python?

Comment: What method are you using to start the thread?

Comment: And Linux or Windows?

Comment: In what use case you need this logic? Why don't you use 2 threads or do all of it in the main thread?